# Data Extract based on index

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean some files.
My data looks as followings, 'Data' is the column name:

```
                                Data
0   3 PM Mon 24th-Mar-2014___0.384 kwh
1   5AM 15-Ago-2014___1.201 kwh
2   __8PM Thu 20-Mar-2014____1.523 kwh
3   6PM 23rd-Abr-2014___0.424 kwh
4   _1AM Friday 19th-Dic-2014___0.209 kwh
```

So, in my opinion, the best way to store it for data analysis is:

```
      Kwh      Hour     Date
0    0.384      3PM  24-Mar-2014
1    1.201      5AM  15-Ago-2014
2    1.523      8PM  20-Mar-2014
3    0.424      6PM  23-Abr-2014
4    0.209      1AM  19-Dic-2014
```

But, as you can see, the hour it isn´t at the same format along the column, so, base on the 'M' index, I want to slice the 'Data column' to store it on "Hour", my file right now looks like this:

```
                      Data               indices       Kws
0   3 PM Mon 24-Mar-2014 0.384              3         0.384
1   5AM 15-Ago-2014 1.201                   2         1.201
2   8PM Thu 20-Mar-2014 1.523               2         1.523
3   6PM 23-Abr-2014 0.424                   2         0.424
4   1AM Friday 19-Dic-2014 0.20             2         0.209
```

But I can´t get rid of the 'Kws' value on the data column and extract the 'Hour' value on the data colum neither.

What do you guys think, is there a better way to do it?
How can I:

- Extract the hour on 'Data' column
- Get rid of the 'KWs' value on the 'Data' column.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Use „df.Data.apply(lambda x: x.split(“M”)[0])”. Apply also has a parameter to return multiple columns. You will probably have to fiddle with the lambda function or declare one.

Comment: Use [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a custom regex to extract all in one go.